# why does the linker change shared library name?

Tags: linker, ld, node-gyp

Using linker command line options passed via 'node-gyp' I specify that the library path and library name that I want the program to link with. But the resulting executable does not reference the file I specified, it references a different name in `/usr/lib`.

I'm using the libraries section in `binding.gyp` to reference a local `lib` directory.

```
      'libraries': [
        '-lao-oboe',
        '-L<(module_root_dir)/lib/',
        '-Wl,-rpath-link,<(module_root_dir)/lib/',
        '-Wl,-rpath,<(module_root_dir)/lib/'
      ],
```

`node-gyp` seems to be passing the options correctly because the linker returns `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -la-oboe` if I change the `-L` path to one that doesn't contain `libao-oboe.so`. The linker also returns an error if I change the name of the requested library to be different than the one in `lib`.

The problem is that the local library will not be loaded at runtime. `ldd` shows that the `node-gyp` output file is not referencing the file that was specified - it is referencing a library with a different name altogether - `/usr/lib/liboboe-1.0.so.1`. See the second line of `ldd` output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffee20f5000)
liboboe-1.0.so.1 => /usr/lib/liboboe-1.0.so.1 (0x00007fa476377000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa475ff5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa475c2b000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa475a27000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa47580a000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa475501000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa476922000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa4752eb000)
```

The local library directory contains:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 bruce bruce      15 Sep  8 02:50 libao-oboe.so -> libao-oboe.so.1`  
-rw-r--r--  2 bruce bruce 1640848 Aug 31 15:01 libao-oboe.so.1
```

It is the case that the local library file, `libao-oboe.so.1` is the same as the system library file being referenced in the executable (as shown by `ldd`): `/usr/lib/liboboe-1.0.so.1`.

Does the linker somehow notice that the local file is the same (via hashing or some signature) and substituting the library file from the standard location?

Why does `node-gyp`'s output file reference a library file that was never requested as part of the build process?

Comment: The 'soname' field in the .so file ends up replacing the filename specified in the -l option. I don't understand exactly what is going on, but if I make the filename match the soname then there is no problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [wikipedia - soname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname) the SONAME field in the `.so` file is the "base compatible version". It's clear from the behavior I found in the problem above that `ld` inserts the SONAME into the file being linked to the shared library - not the filename specified in the `ld` command.

Renaming a `.so` file doesn't change the SONAME so an executable linked to a renamed file will try to load a library named by the SONAME field, not the filename.

My solution was to not rename the file.